# Loaded a dictionary with integer key how do I print it out?

Tags: python, dictionary, int

in Python 27

```
p=100
dicthg = {}

for i in range(10):
    print i
    dicthg = {i:p};

for i in range(10):
    print "-", i
    print dicthg[i]
```

key error
comment out the second for loop and it prints dicthg[i] fine.

tried on second for loop

```
for i in dicthg:
```

got last item only (index 9)

same when

```
for i,j in dicthg.items():
     print i,j
```

I am new to Python so I apologize in advance for my ignorance. I have made an extensive search of previous posts.

Comment: Try printing `dicthg` before entering the second loop.

Answer (score 0):

You are not loading it. You are replacing the entire dictionary in every iteration of the loop. Here is how you *load* it.

```
for i in range(10):
    print i
    dicthg[i] = p
```

Answer (score 0):

This is making a new dictionary with only 1 element every time

```
for i in range(10):
    print i
    dicthg = {i:p}
```

Right now, `dicthg` has the following value

```
{9: 100}
```

I assume your intention was the following

```
for i in range(10):
    print i
    dicthg[i] = p
```

Now look at the dictionary

```
{0: 100, 1: 100, 2: 100, 3: 100, 4: 100, 5: 100, 6: 100, 7: 100, 8: 100, 9: 100}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
p=100 
dicthg = {i:p for i in range(10)}
```

Another method of creating a dictionary using a dictionary comprehension.

Answer (score 0):

To get your code working just replace:

```
dicthg = {i:p}
```

for

```
dicthg.update({i:p})
```

If you want an easy way to know what's going on, add this line to the first loop:

```
print dicthg
```

this will show you why the `KeyError` in the second loop.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a modified version of your program:

```
p=100
dicthg = {}

for i in range(10):
    print i
    # This is correct/simple way of setting item in dictionary
    dicthg[i] = p

print "value of i = " + str(i)

print "Setting i to 0 again"
i = 0

print "new value of i = " + str(i)

for i in range(10):
    print "-", i
    print dicthg[i]
```

So I have made two modifications:

1. Insertion/Addition of items in the dictionary
2. Resetting the value of i to 0, so that we can iterate from 0 to 10

Hope this helps!